# .htaccess removes trailing periods from query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Having some trouble where .htaccess is removing the trailing period from strings. I am running Apache/2.2.12 (Win32).

This is not a production system, so there is nothing else in .htaccess other than:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

...and rules, and this works well in all cases so far, unless there is a trailing period in the name. Rules all take the form of:

```
RewriteRule ^thing/(.*)$ showthing.php?thingname=$1
```

A link on A.php:

```
<a href="thing/M.O.X."> ...CLICK
```

So in *showthing.php*, I simply do:

```
$sTHINGname= !isset($_REQUEST['thingname']) ? NULL : $_REQUEST['thingname'];
```

...then *$sTHINGname* is run though the db to find the ID.

The trouble is that when `thingname` has a trailing period (e.g.: "**M.O.X.**")

```
echo $sTHINGname;  // shows M.O.X, which does not match an ID
```

One solution is to do:

```
str_replace( '.', '%2E', $name );
```

But when the links are placed in the referring page (A.php), and this works, but the links read:

```
<a href="thing/M%252EO%252EC%252E">
```

...which is a bit inelegant and does not solve the problem, because if a user types as a URL "...thing/**M.O.X.**" they still don't get a result.

I checked out replacing $_REQUEST with $_GET, but the result doesn't change. Also:

```
RewriteRule ^(thing/)(.*)$ showthing.php?thingname=$2
```

...and variations all show the same results.

Most search results dealing with htaccess and periods are domain issues, so I wonder if anyone has any ideas about this one?

Comment: Do you have a `[L]` on that `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^thing/(.+)$ showthing.php?thingname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: (via OP): thanks for suggesting. [L] has no effect, and neither does [NE]

Comment: The change was `*` to `+` in addition to the flags. I didn't only add the flags.